# Why did Lord Rama pray to Goddess Durga?

Tags: ramayana, rama, durga

Lord Rama is an incarnation of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. Goddess Durga being the external (Maya) potency of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, why did Lord Rama perform a Yagya of Goddess Durga before killing Ravana as mentioned in Ramayana?

Comment: Where did you read in Ramayana that Lord Rama performed a Yagya of Goddess Durga before killing Ravana ? @subha26

Comment: I actually heard it from my grandmother and mother, rather than reading it. They referenced from the Bengali translation of Ramayana by Krittibas Ojha. And Google results also repeats the same.

Comment: As far as Valmiki Ramayana, which is an authentic text on Ramayana, is concerned, there is no such mention.  It might be a folklore, probably linked to the belief that Sri Rama eliminated Ravana in Dussehera time and reached Ayodhya before Deepavali.@subha26

Comment: Maybe. I also saw the link https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga105/yuddha_105_frame.htm and there is no such mention. Can you help me with any reference to the original version. Thanks a lot. But why was he even told to pray Sun god.

Comment: What you had referred to in the link you had provided is one of good sites on Ramayana.  Coming to the aspect of praying to Sun, it is very difficult to say.  Ramayana was composed in post vedic period and when Yajurveda was ruling the land.(Sri rama was mentioned as Yajurveda vineetasya - an expert in yajurveda).  Sun was also adored in Rig Veda.  Perhaps to restore the importance of Sun, this stotra might have been included by Sage valmiki.@subha26

Comment: I have posted my answer here:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/did-lord-rama-worship-devi-ambika/

Answer (score 0):

Saga Agastya preached Aditya Hrudhaya Stotra to The Lord Rama and informs him to perform Navratri pooja and yagna to The Goddess Durga to defeat Ravana.

Reference from Tyagaraja keerthanalu "Manasa Sancharare"

```
 Maanasa Sancharare Brahmani Maanasa Sancharare
 Madasikhi Pinchaalankruta Chikure
 Madasikhi Pinchaalankruta Chikure
 Mahaneeya Kapolajita Mukure Maanasa Sancharare E
 Sree Ramaneekucha  Sree Ramaneekuncha
 Sree Ramaneekucha Durga Vihaari
 Sevakajana Mandira Mandhaare
 Paramahamsamukha Chandra  Chakore. E
 Pari Poorita Muraleeravadhaare
 Maanasa Sancharare
```

Besides, Ram leela is observed on 10th day(Dushera) after navratri. Lord Rama killed the deamon Ravana after he performed navratri pooja.

Comment: Can you please site the reference from where you got this story?

Comment: Hello, please check [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/6981) and edit your answer

Comment: Can you please add the meaning of the shlokas  in answer also ? .